# Change blobFromImage dimensions order in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I faced a problem with C++ blobFromImage function in OpenCV. I trained a CNN-network in Keras which takes a 4-d blob as input (common practice, nothing special). The problem is that my blob order is NHWC (where Channle size is always 6) but blobFromImage returns only NCHW. There is no any trouble to reshape numpy-blob in python but I haven't found any solution for C++.

Input data is two 3-channel images stitched together (at channel axis) in one blob. For example, if images resolution is 1280x720 than blob shape will be (1, 720, 1280, 6)

Is there any way to create blob of NHWC in C++ or reshape blobFromImage result to NHWC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you received an answer to your question in the [OpenCV forum](https://answers.opencv.org/question/236816/change-blobfromimage-dimensions-order/)

> assuming, you have 2 (float) images A and B of equal size, 3 channels each, you could first merge them like this:
>
> ```cpp
> vector<Mat> v = {A,B};
> Mat C;
> merge(v, C);
> ```
>
> now C has 6 interleaved channels, and we need to add the "batch" dimension:
>
> ```cpp
> int sz[] = {1, A.rows, A.cols, 6};
> Mat blob(4, sz, CV_32F, C.data);
> ```
>
> but careful ! your blob does NOT hold a deep copy of the data, so C has to be kept alive during the processing !
>
> EDIT: due to public demand, here's the reverse operation ;)
>
> ```cpp
> // extract 2d, 6chan Mat 
> Mat c2(blob.size[2], blob.size[3], CV_32FC(6), blob.ptr(0));
>
> // split into channels
> vector<Mat> v2;
> split(c2,v2);
>
> // merge back into 2 images
> Mat a,b;
> merge(vector<Mat>(v2.begin(),   v2.begin()+3), a);
> merge(vector<Mat>(v2.begin()+3, v2.end()),     b);
> ```

Comment: That's right, the answer helped me.